# Matching code was not found or was already used

Tags: ios, api, instagram

I am trying to use the Instagram OAuth using the developer documentation at

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started

Step 1 and 2 are working without any problems, so I have my Client-ID, the Client-Secret, the Redirect-URI and the code.

18
I am trying to use the Instagram OAuth using the developer documentation at

https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/.

Step 1 and 2 are working without any problems, so I have my Client-ID, the Client-Secret, the Redirect-URI and the code.

But every-time I am trying to get the Acces Token I get the following error:

{
"code": 400, 
"error_type": "OAuthException", 
"error_message": "Matching code was not found or was already used."
}

Any tips how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions from Facebook link you posted not Instagram (they won't work for the new API):

Redirect for user authorization:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize
?app_id={app-id}
&redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
&scope=user_profile,user_media
&response_type=code
```

Exchange the code returned for a token:

```
curl -X POST \
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token \
-F app_id={app-id} \
-F app_secret={app-secret} \
-F grant_type=authorization_code \
-F redirect_uri={redirect-uri} \
-F code={code}
```